# How to close all unused ports

Tags: windows, windows-vista, ports, nmap

Whenever i do nmap on my system it shows most of the ports open.How to make only default ports open.I am using Windows Vista with Service Pack 2

Comment: Use a [firewall.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

Comment: Vista shouldn't have any ports open unless they're being used by some process. If "most of the ports" were open, that would be over 60000 ports, and your computer would grind to a crawl. If you want to close a port, you need to find out what process opened it, which you can do by using the `/o` switch when running `netstat` and then using `tasklist` or task manager to find out which process that is. You can then disable the service/program that's listening on that port.